# How do I disable the border on bootstrap 4 cards

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

A grey outline keeps appearing on the img section of my bootstrap card, which I would like to remove. 
 [image: Bootstrap card]

```
    <!-- Card deck -->
                <div class="card-deck">
                    <!-- Card -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                            <!--Card image-->
                            <div class="view overlay"><img alt="Work eyewear" class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/clothing-1.jpg"></div><!--Card content-->
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <!--Title-->
                                <h4 class="card-title">PPE</h4><!--Text-->
                                <p class="card-text">PPE is equipment that will protect the user against health or safety risks at work...</p><!-- Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons -->
                                <a class="" href="https://shop.spartansafety.co.uk/personal-protection-s/1820.htm">SHOP NOW <i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-xs"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Card -->
```

Comment: Inserting your code into a snippet does not show that grey border.  Can you provide additional markup?

Comment: (https://jsfiddle.net/webi108/dmerj8t5/1/)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you check the `.card` class has a `border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;`

To remove it simply override it to `border: none;`

Comment: FYI: There are available Bootstrap Classes to do this without having to modify the css. Refer to the other answers

Comment: You are changing a default property so you need to add !important;

Answer (score 132):

There are [border utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/) that can help with this. From the link:

> Subtractive
>
> ```
> <span class="border-0"></span>
> <span class="border-top-0"></span>
> <span class="border-right-0"></span>
> <span class="border-bottom-0"></span>
> <span class="border-left-0"></span>
> ```

So for your scenario, since you want to remove all borders you would add the `border-0` CSS Class to your `card` like so:

```
<div class="card mb-4 border-0">
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the whole point of using a framework is not having to write custom CSS or override elements manually.

Comment: If using Bootstrap 5, change `border-left-0` and `border-right-0` to `border-start-0` and `border-end-0`.

Answer (score 28):

simply, you can make the border zero, `<div class="card border-0">`

Comment: border-0 worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It's better to play with the bootstrap variables. You can customize default cards style with these variables and it won't override Bootstrap CSS. You can check on here how to do this.
[Bootstrap theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/)

```
// Cards

$card-spacer-y:                     .75rem !default;
$card-spacer-x:                     1.25rem !default;
$card-border-width:                 $border-width !default;
$card-border-radius:                $border-radius !default;
$card-border-color:                 rgba($black, .125) !default;
$card-inner-border-radius:          subtract($card-border-radius, $card-border-width) !default;
$card-cap-bg:                       rgba($black, .03) !default;
$card-cap-color:                    null !default;
$card-height:                       null !default;
$card-color:                        null !default;
$card-bg:                           $white !default;
$card-img-overlay-padding:          1.25rem !default;
$card-group-margin:                 $grid-gutter-width / 2 !default;
$card-deck-margin:                  $card-group-margin !default;
$card-columns-count:                3 !default;
$card-columns-gap:                  1.25rem !default;
$card-columns-margin:               $card-spacer-y !default;
```

Comment: Interesting! Is this new to Bootstrap? This would affect all `card` elements right?

Comment: It was there when the Bootstrap 4 is released. Yes, definitely affect all the card elements.